# What is the mode of a continuous random variable?

Tags: probability, soft-question

Consider a "discrete" random variable $X$. A mode of $X$ is just a maximizer of $P(X = x)$. This is obviously useful, and we can easily see that a mode is a "most likely" value for $X$.

If, instead, we have a "continuous" real-valued random variable $X$ with a [PDF](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Probability_Density_Function) $f_{X}$, I think we usually define a mode of $X$ to be a maximizer of $f_{X}$. I have two questions:

1. How can we interpret the mode of a continuous random variable? In other words, why is the mode of a continuous random variable useful to probability theory?

   - [Some](https://www.radfordmathematics.com/probabilities-and-statistics/continuous-probability-distributions/parameters-continuous-random-variables/parameters-continuous-random-variables.html) [websites](https://analystprep.com/study-notes/actuarial-exams/soa/p-probability/univariate-random-variables/explain-and-calculate-expected-value-mode-median-percentile-and-higher-moments/) say that it is "the value most likely to lie within the same interval as the outcome", but I can't make sense of that.
   - Some people point to the obvious [geometric visualization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mode_(statistics)#/media/File:Visualisation_mode_median_mean.svg) of the mode (as the peak of the PDF) but I don't think that justifies the usefulness of the mode at all.
2. Is there a more general definition of mode, removing the assumptions above that $X$ is real-valued and has a PDF?

Comment: I'm not sure I agree that the mode of a discrete variable is "obviously useful" -- but if you accept that premise, then take your continuous random variable and discretize your scale. (That is, bin nearby outcomes together in "buckets".) If your discretization is fine enough, your most frequent bucket will correspond with the highest peak on the density curve. That is: the two ideas of "mode" are basically the same, which is to capture the place you are most likely to find your variable.

Comment: As for general definitions, for continuous random variables, I am only aware of the definition as a density maximizer (which presumes a density exists). However, any *local* maximizer is sometimes also referred to as a *mode* so that we may call a density having many local maxima *multimodal*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Intuitively, the significance of a mode (in the sense of a density maximizer) is that for sufficiently small fixed interval size $\epsilon$, a real-valued random variable $X$ having density $f$ is more likely to realize values in an interval containing the mode than otherwise. Letting $\epsilon\rightarrow 0$ then gives rise to a mode. More formally, by the fundamental theorem of calculus, a mode $m$ satisfies

$$m\in  \arg\max_a \lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{\epsilon }\int_a^{a+\epsilon}f(x)dx.$$

As for your question on usefulness, finding a mode for a continuous distribution has applications in estimation theory, among other things (e.g. [MLE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood_estimation), [MAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_a_posteriori_estimation)). Given that a mode captures where data is "most likely" to occur (in the above limit sense), finding a mode gives at least a compelling way to choose an estimator.

Answer (score 3):

The intuition for the probability density function $f_X(x)$ of a random variable $X$ is that the chance of $X$ taking values between $a\pm dx/2$ for some very small $dx$ is given by $f_X(a)\cdot dx$. This makes sense in that $\int_{\Omega} f_X(x) dx = 1$ so that the sum of all these "infinitesimal probabilities" is $1$.

So if $f_X(m)$ is the maximal value of $f_X(x)$ then the chance of $X$ taking values between $m\pm dx/2$ is larger that the chance of $X$ taking values in any other interval of length $dx$ (for "small" $dx$). This intuition is what justifies calling $m$ the mode of $X$.