Mode of Gamma not in the support
The PDF of a gamma random variable with $\alpha=k<1$ strictly decreases from $x=0$ to $x=\infty$. The answer does not make any conclusions about the value of the mode.
Wikipedia tells me

Mode of a gamma distribution with $\alpha=k<1$ is zero.
Gamma random variable has support $x>0$.

So how is it possible for $0$ (not in the support) to be its mode?
Even if it's something like $x\rightarrow0^+$, then $x=0$ is not in the domain of the function, and it will not have a local maximum, the function will keep increasing as x gets closer and closer to zero.

The issue here is that we're looking for the supremum, not the maximum. To be completely rigorous, we can define the mode of random variable $\xi$
using $x(\epsilon)$ where
$$
x(\epsilon)=\arg\max_{x\in\mathbb R} \mathbb{P}(\xi\in (x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon))
$$
as
as $m:=\lim_{\epsilon\downarrow 0} x(\epsilon)$. This definition will even work for the discrete random variables.

I haven't really seen this kind of definition before. Could you give a reference of a book where it would be covered.

Please see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4378105/what-is-the-mode-of-a-continuous-random-variable
